# 403 Error Web Scraping with R with Specified User Agent

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data off of the website [GovSalaries](https://govsalaries.com/), which doesn't appear to be a violation of their terms of service (although I didn't look that hard). However, I keep getting a 403 error. I tried adding headers to my code that I found from the http request using a web browser with no luck. Below is an example,

```
ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
url = "https://govsalaries.com/salaries/FD/food-and-drug-administration"
my_page = GET(url, user_agent(ua))
```

I'm guessing it may have to do with cookies? Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: I tried to start a "session" with the main page, but am still getting a 403 error. The idea being I could then `jump_to` the page of interest. Thanks to @r2evans for suggesting this approach (although it didn't work in this example, seems like a good strategy).

```
## example
ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
url = "https://govsalaries.com/"
my_session = session(url, user_agent(ua))
```

Comment: My guess is that their heuristics for trying to slow down or stop undesired web-scraping is to make it hard to do so. However, it could also be that having a referrer could help. Try using `rvest` instead of `httr`, start a "session" with the main `.com` page, then `jump_to` the page you want. I don't know that it'll work, but it's another strategy. (I'm inferring that the user-agent you're using here is copied from your actual browser that does _not_ receive a 403, that's what would give you the best chance of success.)

Comment: Does `RSelenium` solution works for you?

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! I gave your suggestion a try, but still no luck. I updated my post to reflect what I tried. Seems like a good general strategy though.

Comment: @NadPat I'm not familiar with `RSelenium`, would you be able to provide a MWE with the site info I provided above?

Comment: I was half way through solving the problem, but then the site started asking to solve captcha which is difficult to do using `RSelenium`

Comment: [1/n] I just spent a bit of time on this, trying to add various headers (I tried everything that my regular browser is sending), no luck. I tried (superficially!) to use [`V8`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/index.html), again 403. I even tried adding all of the cookies from the browser session (viewed in the FF dev console), still 403.

Comment: [2/n] Each time, the lead portion of the 403 response starts with `<meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />` and includes the text *"Please enable cookies and reload"* (which is not a clear indicator, as `rvest::session` *is* collecting cookies, as shown by `res$response$cookies`.

Comment: [3/3] Bottom line, I think this site's ninja-fu skills on preventing web-scraping surpasses my patience atm, and I am inferring a very strong preference to not be scraped. Considering the data being made available, I'm not surprised, as scraping it would be a great feeder for other social-engineering woes (in addition to legitimate academic research). I think you're battling an army of strong-ninja-fu sysadmis. Good luck.

Comment: @r2evans Appreciate the help & effort! You confirmed what I suspected, a strong army of ninja-fu sysadmins. This may be beyond my skill to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is partial answer,

```
#start browser
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(
     port = 4847L,
       browser = c("firefox"))

#navigate
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
url = "https://govsalaries.com/salaries/FD/food-and-drug-administration"
remDr$navigate(url)

#get the links 
link = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.table-sm') %>% html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr('href')
link = unique(link)
link = paste0('https://govsalaries.com', link)
head(link)
[1] "https://govsalaries.com/califf-robert-58583316"           "https://govsalaries.com/woodcock-janet-58598162"         
[3] "https://govsalaries.com/midthun-karen-58591778"           "https://govsalaries.com/jenkins-john-k-58588605"         
[5] "https://govsalaries.com/moscicki-richard-arthur-58592168" "https://govsalaries.com/shuren-jeffrey-e-58595518"
```

After extracting links when we start to loop through each link to scrape wages captcha starts appearing.

[image]

Then closed the browser and started fresh browser and navigated to one of the link that we extracted before

```
url = "https://govsalaries.com/califf-robert-58583316"
#get the tables 
tab = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_table()
```

Here the first two tables may be important to you,

```
tab[[1]]
# A tibble: 12 x 2
   X1                                       X2                            
   <chr>                                    <chr>                         
 1 "Year"                                   "2015"                        
 2 "Full Name"                              "Robert Califf"               
 3 "Original Job Title"                     "MEDICAL OFFICER"             
 4 "Job Title"                              "Medical Officer"             
 5 "Get Medical Officer\nSalary Statistics" ""                            
 6 "State"                                  "Federal"                     
 7 "Employer"                               "FOOD AND DRUG ADMINISTRATION"
 8 "Location"                               "SILVER SPRING"               
 9 "Annual Wage"                            "$300,000"                    
10 "Bonus"                                  "N/A"                         
11 "Pay Plan"                               "RF"                          
12 "Grade"                                  "00"  

tab[[2]]
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  X1                  X2                          
  <chr>               <chr>                       
1 Employer Name       FOOD AND DRUG ADMINISTRATION
2 Year                2015                        
3 Number of Employees 17,594                      
4 Average Annual Wage $110,621                    
5 Median Annual Wage  $110,902
```

But when i navigated to another link again hit a captcha. One obvious solution would be start new browser every time. Or you should come up with some unique method or hack or something.